# TSQL, join to multiple fields of which one could be NULL

Tags: t-sql

I have a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM Products p 
LEFT JOIN SomeTable st ON st.SomeId = p.SomeId AND st.SomeOtherId = p.SomeOtherId
```

So far so good.

But the first join to SomeId can be NULL, In that case the check should be IS NULL, and that's where the join fails. I tried to use a CASE, but can't get that to work also.

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: So if `SomeId` is `NULL` in `Products` it should join with those rows where it is `NULL` in `SomeTable`? You want equality semantics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Undocumented Query Plans: Equality Comparisons](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx).

```
SELECT *
FROM   Products p
       LEFT JOIN SomeTable st
         ON st.SomeOtherId = p.SomeOtherId
            AND EXISTS (SELECT st.SomeId INTERSECT SELECT p.SomeId)
```